# Disable Date Picker on click in tree view Odoo

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo, odoo-9, bootstrap-datepicker

I have an editable tree view, in which I have a datetime field. Whenever I click on the field it opens the date picker.

Is there any option to disable the date picker on click on the field so that it will only open on clicking the calendar icon? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think or known that the requested option exist, you would need to customize the js widget to prevent that behavior